# K/D Ratio with SQL and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I'm trying to make a K/D ratio with some data from a database using SQL.

The main problem is that the tables are so strange and I'm trying to display it as an HTML table.

There's a table called stats_player_kill (when player kills another)

Here's the content of the table:

[image: As u can see is divided with the killer and the victim]

So if I want to get the kills, I count the killer column with the same id.

Here's how I get number of kills of each player and display it as an HTML table:

```
    <table class="tablitas" id="kills">
<thead>
<tr>
<th data-column-id="name">Player</th>
<th data-column-id="killer" data-type="numeric">Kills</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<?php
$sql = "select p.name as name, count(*) as amountOfObjects 
       from stats_player_kill b 
          join stats_player p on p.id = b.victim 
       group by b.victim 
       order by count(*) desc 
       limit 15";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["amountOfObjects"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</td>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

So I need help making the math to divide number of kills by the total deaths.

Sorry for my English and thanks to everyone! :D

Comment: Surely `order by amountOfObjects`

Comment: Maybe you would like to get your HTML ducks in a row first

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of data. They're usually messy, full of unrelated junk, and hard to read, not to mention you can't use them to copy-paste data from.